# Kotlin create object with params syntax

Tags: kotlin

I have an object

```
class Person {
@JsonProperty("name")
var name: String? = null

@JsonProperty("id")
lateinit var id: String}
```

There is an only empty constructor and I want to create a person so I wrote:

```
 val person = Person()
 person.name = "someName"
 person.id = "SomeId"
```

I'm  pretty sure that there is a prettier syntax, something like

```
val person = Person {name = "someName" , id = "someId"}
```

but I can't find an example.
am I missing something? should I create a secondary constructor to use this syntax or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check [apply](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html) method.

Your code will be like this:

```
val person = Person().apply {name = "someName", id = "someId"}
```

**Another way** - you can change declaration of Person to (e.g. just change brackets, replace `var` to `val` and remove `lateinit`):

```
class Person (@JsonProperty("name") val name: String? = null,
              @JsonProperty("id") val id: String )
```

Then you will able to do this:

```
val person = Person(name = "someName", id = "someId")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with the constructor parameter.

```
class Person(
        @JsonProperty("name")
        var name: String? = null,
        @JsonProperty("id")
        var id: String
)



val person = Person(name = "someName", id = "someId")
```

---

Another way is make your class and desired variables open to be overridden.

```
open class Person {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    open var name: String? = null
    @JsonProperty("id")
    open var id: String = ""
}

val person =  object : Person() {
        override var name: String? = "SomeName"
        override var id = "SomeId"
}
```